# Xcode - Capabilities settings

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am using Unity to build an Xcode project. I already implemented in-app purchase and added the StoreKit framework to the project.

But the "Capablities" settings in Xcode shows that the "In-App Purchase" toggle is off.

My purchase on sandbox does work. But I don't know what effect does this "In-App Purchase" button have.

Unity does not have an automatic way to set Capablities settings and I don't want to set it every time.

Should I turn it on?

[image: Capabilities in the Xcode project]

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can ignore it.@DavidSeek

Comment: It matters alot xD I'm using continuous development. That means that the App is build on a Server whenever I push to git. That means it's a clean environment with a clean Xcode. Therefore the Capabilities matter A LOT.